# Mixed entry call and accept select in Ada?

Tags: ada

Is it possible to mix protected entry calls (with barrier) with accepts in one select statement? Without using delays and two different consecutive selects, one for accepts and one for entry calls:

```
task body Task is
begin
  select
    accept Get;
  or
    accept Put;
  or
    Protected_Object.Alive;
  end select;
end Task;

protected body Protected_Object is
begin
  entry Alive when Is_Alive is
  ...
```

I want Task to get locked waiting for a call to Get, Put or getting the barrier in Alive opened.

Comment: I don’t know (IANALL). I could **explore the question by writing some code and trying it** .. but then, so could you

Comment: The code as stated is not allowed according to [ARM 9.7.1 (4)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-7-1.html#p4). Apart from that: `Task` is a reserved word (see [ARM 2.9](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-9.html)), you cannot use it as an identifier.

Comment: I supposed, so which is the best way to do that? Which is the best/CPU optimum structure to wait/lock for accepts and to make calls to entries with guards? Wait for accepts first and then for callings in a busy waiting manner or with a delay?

Comment: @Simon my question was wrong. I know this code is illegal. I was looking for a good solution to do what an hypothetical code like this may do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives depending on what you expect to happen more often:

If you expect/want the Get/Put to happen more often than Alive:

```ada
task body Test is
begin
    loop
        select
            accept Get;
        or
            accept Put;
        or 
            -- Pick a value that makes sense
            -- This is how long you check Get
            -- and Put before trying Alive
            delay 0.0001;  

            -- Asynchronous transfer of control
            -- will try Protected_Object.Alive
            -- until the second delay is finished
            select
                -- Pick a value that makes sense
                -- Should be much smaller than the above
                -- delay
                delay 0.0000001;  
            then abort
                Protected_Object.Alive;
            end select;

        end select;

    end loop;
end Test;
```

if you expect/want Alive checked more often than Get/Put then:

```ada
task body Test is
begin
    loop
        select
            accept Get;
        or
            accept Put;
        else

            -- Asynchronous transfer of control
            -- will try Protected_Object.Alive
            -- until the delay is finished
            select
                -- Pick a value that makes sense
                delay 0.0001;  
            then abort
                Protected_Object.Alive;
            end select;

        end select;

    end loop;
end Test;
```

Either way, you'll need to decide how/when to end that loop if desired.

Comment: Why do you use ATC rather than a timed or conditional entry call?

Comment: No real reason.  Just the first thing that came to mind.  Was just tossing out possible alternatives since the OP didn't provide an MCVE

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can do:

```
select
   Protected_Object.Alive;
then abort
   select
      accept Get;
   or
      accept Put;
   end select;
end select;
```

which may give you what you want, though understanding ATC can be tricky.

Comment: I have compilation error "accept statements are not allowed within an asynchronous select inner to the enclosing task body" using this structure.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Sorry for the misinformation. For those who are interested, this is prohibited in ARM 9.5.2(15).